# Probability of being selected, rigged lottery

Tags: probability, lotteries

I participated in a lottery game, with $N$ different participants and $k$ prizes. Participants were random selected, and each one can only win one prize: after a person is selected they are eliminated from the lottery (i.e., no reinsertion).

The game was run a first time, let's call it $game1$.

After the winners were selected, organizers found out there were some fake participants (some people submitted their application multiple times), say this is $m$. Some of them even won a prize, say this is $j$.

Organizers decided to remove the $m$ cheaters, the $k-j$ legit winners, and select $j$ new winners. Let's call this game $game2$

The parameters for $game2$ were:

$N^{'} = N - m - k + j$

$k^{'} = j$

If the organizers instead decided to run the game from scratch after eliminating cheaters, in a hypothetical game named $game3$, we would have:

$N^{''} = N - m$

$k^{''} = k$

Given that, I calculated:

- the probability of winning $game1$, $P^{1}_{win}$
- the probability of winning $game2$, $P^{2}_{win}$
- the probability of winning $game3$, $P^{3}_{win}$
- the probability of winning the second game, not having won the first, $P^{'}_{win}$

My questions are:

1. would the solution of “incrementally” re-running the game (i.e., $game2$ after $game1$) exactly the same as $P^{3}_{win}$?
2. is the overall process fair for everyone? In other words, could there be at least one person who had a different probability of winning depending on being selected or not selected in the first round ($game1$)?

--

My reasoning:

In this kind of lottery you need to calculate the probability of being selected, $P_{win}$, considering that, at each extraction, the number of participants goes down at each extraction, as the number of remaining prizes. So you have

$P_{win}=\frac{1}{N}+\frac{1}{N-1}\left( 1-\frac{1}{N}\right)+\frac{1}{N-2}\left\{ 1-\left[ \frac{1}{N}+\frac{1}{N-1}\left( 1-\frac{1}{N} \right) \right] \right\}+...$
(k times)

We can use that formula to calculate $P^{1}_{win}$, $P^{2}_{win}$, and $P^{3}_{win}$.

As per $P^{'}_{win}$ it should be:

$P^{'}_{win}=\left( 1 - P^{1}_{win} \right)P^{2}_{win}$

So, assuming I am not mistaken, I would like to validate the following answers:

1. $P^{3}_{win}$ and $P^{'}_{win}$ are different
2. This is were I am undecided. I have the feeling that people who won $game1$ had a lesser chance to be selected than people who ran for $game1$, were not selected, and then ran for $game2$ (so the process was not fair for the winners of $game1$). But the overall process is "fair" because everyone was in the same situation (i.e., could win $game1$ OR $game2$)

Comment: The bottom line was my first question.  You ask a multipart question, expecting us to provide a full solution, without you having invested any time or thought to it.  We are not a "do my homework" site.

Comment: 1. Please specify the probabilistic process more clearly.  Does the lottery randomly select one of the N participants to be  winner, uniformly at random, repeated k times, without replacement?  That should be stated in the question -- I shouldn't have to guess.  2. Where did you encounter this?  Can you credit the original source?  3. Please define the events more precisely.  What do you mean by "probability of winning the first game?" Which is the first game?  Probability for whom to win the first game?  Please [edit] your question to make the question clearer.

Comment: @D.W., hopefully it's better now. This was not in a textbook, it was IRL.

Comment: I'm afraid you need to define the probabilities (and the random process) more precisely.  Let's say in this particular incident you detected 7 cheaters, 3 of whom won.  Are you asking for the probability that you win, given that there were 7 cheaters, 3 of whom won?  Or are you asking for the probability that you win, without conditioning on how many cheater win?  If you were to repeat the experiment many times, the number of times that cheaters win will vary from run to run.  Are you only interested in trials with 3 cheater-winners, or in all trials?

Comment: In either scenario, the number of legit participants and winners do not change. Legit participants are all in the same position, with no advantages or disadvantages over the others. Therefore, the chance to win remains the same: $\frac{k}{N-m}$

Comment: @D.W. thanks. That is actually something I didn’t think about so it’s part of the answer I was looking for. My final goal is to understand whether organisers did the right thing or they should have repeated the game from scratch to give everyone the same chances of winning (regardless of whether they win or not in the rigged game). What do you suggest we could use for evaluating that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a surprisingly tricky question!  It is tricky, because turning your question ("is this fair?") into a mathematical question about probability and statistics is quite subtle, and requires making assumptions about what the organizers would have done in other situations.

The short answer is, it's not possible to answer whether it is fair, because you can't know what the organizer would have done if circumstances had turned out differently.  What counts as "fair" is non-trivial to define in a precise mathematical way.  I would argue that fairness is a property of the procedure or process that the organizers use, not just what they did in one instance.  You don't know what the organizers would have done in a counterfactual setting where things turned out differently, so you can't know whether it is fair.

For instance, suppose that the organizers were malicious, and behave as follows: if their friend Bob is one of the winners in Game 1, they remove the cheaters, keep the non-cheating winners, and rerun for everyone else (i.e., Game 2); whereas if their friend Bob is not one of the winners in Game 1, they rerun everything (Game 3).  In this case, then it clearly wouldn't be fair: Bob would have an elevated chance of winning, and everyone else would have a decreased chance of winning.  Call this Scenario A.

On the other hand, suppose that the organizers behave as follows in all possible scenarios: if cheaters are detected in Game 1, then they always keep the winners, remove the cheaters, and re-run on everyone else (Game 2).  In that case, it is fair.  The probability of winning in Game 1+Game 2 is the same as for Game 3, as explained in [Rezha Adrian Tanuharja's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4836834/14578).  Call this Scenario B.

Now, you tell us that you observed a situation where some people won in Game 1, cheaters were detected, and the organizers decided to keep the winners, remove the cheaters, and re-run the rest (Game 2).  Can we tell, from that fact alone, whether everything is fair?  No, we can't.  Both Scenario A and B are consistent with the observed data.  We don't know whether one of the winners from Game 1 might have been one of the organizers' friends, and we don't know what would have happened if none of the organizers' friends had won Game 1.

Of course if the organizers had decided to rerun everything (Game 3), we can make the same objection: we have no way of knowing whether the organizers would have done in that in every possible case, or if they were just biased against the people who happened to win Game 1 in this one iteration.

So, it's not answerable whether the process is fair, and it's not obvious what is the fair thing to do in this situation.

Arguably, what the organizers did is reasonable.  It would be reasonable for observers to always object to rerunning everything from scratch (Game 3) and never object to rerunning just the non-winners (Game 2); if everyone agreed to do that, that would ensure that the organizers can never get away with something unfair.  Unfortunately, it would also be reasonable for observers to always object to rerunning just the non-winners (Game 2) and never object to rerunning everything from scratch (Game 3); if everyone agreed to do that, that would also ensure that the organizers can never get away with something unfair.  There is no obvious mathematical way to specify which of these two policies observers should adapt.  As a result, in practice, there could easily be some people who follow the first policy, and some people who follow the second policy, leaving observers in a pickle where nothing satisfies everyone.

---

How does this connect to probability theory?  One way to look at this is that there is a difference between $\Pr[\text{win}|E_j]$ vs $\Pr[\text{win}]$, where here $E$ is the event that exactly $j$ of the cheaters won Game 1, and $\text{win}$ is the probability that you are one of the winners at the end.  We have

$$\Pr[\text{win}] = \sum_{j=0}^{\min(m,k)} \Pr[\text{win}|E_j] \Pr[E_j].$$

Let's say that in universe $U_{12}$, we always run Game 1, then discard all cheaters, and run Game 2 (keep the winners from Game 1 and re-run with whoever remains), while in universe $U_{3}$, we always run Game 1, then discard all cheaters, and run Game 3 (rerun everything from scratch).

As [Rezha Adrian Tanuharja's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4836834/14578) shows, we have

$$\Pr_{U_{12}}[\text{win}] = \Pr_{U_{3}}[\text{win}].$$

In other words,

$$\sum_{j=0}^{\min(m,k)} \Pr_{U_{12}}[\text{win}|E_j] \Pr_{U_{12}}[E_j]
=
\sum_{j=0}^{\min(m,k)} \Pr_{U_{3}}[\text{win}|E_j] \Pr_{U_{3}}[E_j].$$

Also, we have $\Pr_{U_{12}}[E_j] = \Pr_{U_{3}}[E_j]$.  However, we do *not* have $\Pr_{U_{12}}[\text{win}|E_j] = \Pr_{U_{3}}[\text{win}|E_j]$ -- those two probabilities are different.

So we get a different answer to your question, depending whether we interpret it as asking "is discarding the cheaters and re-running the non-winners (assuming we always do that in all circumstances) equivalent to re-running everything from scratch?", or as asking "given that we observed $j$ of the cheaters won in Game 1, is discarding the cheaters and re-running the non-winners equivalent to re-running everything from scratch?".  The answer to the first question is Yes, and the answer to the second question is No.

I hope this illustrates how this is a tricky situation, and the exact answer depends on exactly what question you are asking.  Conditional probabilities are tricky to reason about.

Comment: Thank you! Can’t upvote because I have low rep :)

Comment: I select this as the answer because it includes [Rezha](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4836834/14578)’s answer and adds an analysis of the perceived fairness.

Answer (score 1):

**Game 3**

Game $3$ is essentially choosing $k$ winners out of $N-m$ legit participants. Your chance of winning, i.e. chance that you and $k-1$ other participants win is:

$$
\frac{\binom{N-m-1}{k-1}}{\binom{N-m}{k}}=\frac{k}{N-m}
$$

**Game 1 XOR Game 2**

Your chance of winning game $1$ is:

$$
\sum_{j=0}^{\min\left(m,k-1\right)}
\frac{
\binom{m}{j}\binom{N-m-1}{k-j-1}
}{
\binom{N}{k}
}
=
\frac{k}{N}
$$

Your chance of not winning game $1$ but winning game $2$ is:

$$
\sum_{j=0}^{\min\left(m,k\right)}
\frac{
\binom{m}{j}\binom{N-m-1}{k-j}
}{
\binom{N-m}{k}
}
\cdot
\frac{\binom{N-m-k+j-1}{j-1}}{\binom{N-m-k+j}{j}}
=
\frac{m}{N-m}\cdot
\frac{k}{N}
$$

**Comparison**

Let's compare the chance to win in each scenario:

$$
\frac{k}{N-m}
=
\frac{k}{N} +
\frac{m}{N-m}\cdot\frac{k}{N}
$$

Therefore, whichever scenario the lottery game host choose, your chance of winning remains the same.

Comment: Would considering people (vs people plus fake account) change that logic? I think in both my calculation above and this one we are considering players separate entities.

Comment: Moreover, with the strategy adopted by the organisers, if no cheater won, then game2 would have never happened. And in that case, game1 would have had a non uniform probability of being selected, if we consider people playing (I.e people who created fake accounts are like they bought multiple tickets)

Comment: @robwilliams I didn't get what you mean, which non-uniform probability are you talking about?

Comment: If we consider that some people, in game1, had multiple “tickets” (i.e., fake accounts), the probability is not equals for every person participating, I think.

Comment: So I am wondering whether it’s not the probability of a “ticket” (account) to be selected we should consider in evaluating the “fairness” and  compare the probability for the games; but rather the probability of a person to win. In game 2, removing fake accounts, that is the same, of course.

Comment: @robwilliams a person win if his/her ticket gets selected right? so what's the difference?

Comment: That some people have more than one. Wouldn’t that make a difference?

Comment: @robwilliams that changes the calculation but not the end result. In this lottery game, those who have multiple tickets never win, so the game at its core is always the same: choose $k$ winners out of $N-m$ legit participants and the probability for a particular legit participant to win is always $\frac{k}{N-m}$

Comment: It’s true that they never win (although I should have mentioned that organisers couldn’t point who created multiple accounts)… but in game1 the distribution wasn’t uniform. People who won game1, won a game which wasn’t fair for everyone.

Comment: @robwilliams wasn't fair for whom? As far as the legit participant's concern, everyone has equal chance to win game 1, everyone has equal chance to lose game 1 and win game 2. If I have an extremely rigged coin with $10^{-12}$ chance of landing tails, as long as everyone use this same coin, it's a fair game

Comment: Fair to the first set of winners. They won with a different probability distribution. Nevertheless, it’s true that the overall likelihood is the same for everyone. But my question is: if no cheater had won, so game2 never happened, would game1 have been very different from the game organisers and participants wanted to play (from a probability standpoint)? If that is true, would have made more sense to re-run the game as not all the possible outcome had the same overall probability distribution?

Comment: @robwilliams game 1 and 2 have different probabilities, but those probabilities apply equally to all fair participants. Why do you care too much about the difference in probability between games? As long as all legit participant have equal chance to win, it's fair.

Comment: Because in at least one scenario it would have been a “rigged” game. Specifically, when no fake account won, the game would have a non uniform probability distribution for people (not accounts). This is mainly why I don’t feel like it was a correct decision in the end... but even when we had some winning cheater in game1, thus playing game2, the overall probability wouldn’t have been the one players subscribed for. IMO the game should have been redone from scratch

Comment: But, this is my gut feeling, and that is why I submitted the question here to the experts evaluation 

Comment: @robwilliams again, the cheaters never win, so don't worry about them. The probability is non uniform because cheaters have better chance. However, if you consider only the fair players, their probability is uniform. At the end of the day, it's a competition among only the fair players because the cheaters never win

Comment: Thanks  it makes sense.

Comment: Would the other point, game not being the one people subscribed for, still stand (even with uniform probability)?

Comment: @robwilliams that point is incorrect. The probability to win each game is not what people subscribed for, but the OVERALL probability to win is ALWAYS $\frac{k}{N-m}$. If anything this chance is better than what people subscribed for: $\frac{k}{N}$ before they knew $m$ people are ineligible to win

Comment: Ok. what is confusing to me is that in one scenario (no cheaters were selected and we won’t have game 2) we have $k/N$ while in all the others we would have $k/(N-m)$. Cheaters existed in both scenarios.

Comment: @robwilliams oh no no no. The probability to win in game 1, when cheaters can win, is $\frac{k}{N}$. The conditional probability to win in game 1, with the condition that no cheaters win, is once again $\frac{k}{N-m}$.